# Html onclick on Link+document.getEelementById("email").value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, velo

To be honest, I am very new to Html/javascript. I am trying to create a website from (http://www.wix.com) and it'll contain only a text box and a button.

Wix.com is just a site builder and not supporting the whole website html editing. So I've to use html/javascript to set input textbox and a button.

The main point I would like to know is How to set config on button to go a link(http://www.example.com/)+inputtext(myroom) ... | example:

http://www.example.com/myroom

..... 
I set my textbox id to "email" and trying with many code. But still not working.

Please kindly suggest for me . Thank you in advance.

```
  <button onclick="window.location.href='http://www.example.com/'+document.getEelementById("email").value;">Continue</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
 <button id="btntest">Continue</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btntest").click(function(){
  var emailVal = $("#email").val();
  window.location.href="http://www.example.com/"+emailVal;
});
});
```

Comment: Not still working, Please let me know that an ID determined by dynamic javascript can pass data on call ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your javascript (`getEelementById`), and you use double quotes inside a double quoted string, that's why it does not work.

A simple correction would be :

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/' + document.getElementById('email').value;">Continue</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But still not working. This code onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/'" 
run successfully . But after adding onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/'+ document.getElementById('email').value;"

..........................
it shows nothing and button is not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Let us know whether your input type is text or email with id="email"
>   if its type="text" you can go up with written down code
>
> ```js
> var email_val;
>  function load() {
>  email_val =  document.getElementById('email').value;
>  window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/'+email_val };
> ```
>
> ```html
> <input type="text" id="email">
> <button onClick="load()" >Click Here</button>
> ```

Comment: Thank you for answering Nitin Bagoriya. I know your code will work successfully. But the problem is I am using web builder and it doesn't support the whole web html editing. It only support html/javascript like blogger widget. So I can't write function or assigning variable to be called up. Can you suggest me on this situation. Please kindly help me. I know I need lots of knowledge on web programming.

Comment: Yes, <input type="text" id="email"> as you guessed.

Comment: @AAS, No Problem at all you can use
`<button onClick="javascript:email_val =  document.getElementById('email').value;
 window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/'+email_val" >Click Here</button>`
 It's Working :)

Comment: Sorry bro, I believed your code is superb. It must be wix web builder limitation or something else. Sorry. Thank you so much for trying together with me.